# How to add an append to my powershell script?

Tags: powershell, filter, append

I want to add an append to my script. So if it should crash it gives me the data to this point and dont print like nothing. 
Right now the use of the script is to filter a List by name and Date. After that it remove all names on the blacklist and only contains entries from the month i entered

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Config.xml'
[xml]$blacklist = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Blacklist.xml'



#Names to filter
$BLN = $blacklist.Names
#Import Path
$info = Import-Csv $config.config.path.input -Delimiter ';'
$info | Format-Table
#from which month
#$dateCutoff = get-date "02.2020" -Format "MM.yyyy"
$dateCutoff = $config.config.date
$result = foreach($i in $info){
    if(-Not($blacklist -contains $i.SCAN_USER)){


        $entryDate = get-date $i.SCAN_DATE -Format "MM.yyyy"


        if($entryDate -eq $dateCutoff){
        $i
        }
    }
    Write-Host $i.SCAN_DATE
    }
    #Export path
    $result | Export-Csv $config.config.path.output -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' 
$dateCutoff
```

all my changeble vars are linkt with a config file so you dont have to edit the script every time.

Comment: try just after `-NoTypeInformation`

Comment: sry what should i try after -NoTypeInformations? could you send like a code... im new to powershell^^

Answer (score 0):

```
 Start-Transcript -Path "path to save the transcript" -Append 


 xml]$config = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Config.xml'
 [xml]$blacklist = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Blacklist.xml'



 #Names to filter
 $BLN = $blacklist.Names
 #Import Path
 $info = Import-Csv $config.config.path.input -Delimiter ';' -Verbose
 $info | Format-Table -Verbose 
 #from which month
 #$dateCutoff = get-date "02.2020" -Format "MM.yyyy"
 $dateCutoff = $config.config.date
 $result = foreach($i in $info){
     if(-Not($blacklist -contains $i.SCAN_USER)){


         $entryDate = get-date $i.SCAN_DATE -Format "MM.yyyy"


         if($entryDate -eq $dateCutoff){
         $i
         }
     }
     Write-Host $i.SCAN_DATE
     }
     #Export path
     $result | Export-Csv $config.config.path.output -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'  -Append -Verbose 
 $dateCutoff

 Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: i tried it but was just getting errors and nothing happened...another problem is that without changing anything the $entryDate started sending errors because they mean that "get-Date" cannot be bindet^^ yesterday it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help but i think i got it :) My script looks now like this

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Config.xml'
[xml]$blacklist = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Blacklist.xml'



#Names to filter
$BLN = $blacklist.Names
#Import Path
$info = Import-Csv $config.config.path.input -Delimiter ';'
$info | Format-Table
#from which month
#$dateCutoff = get-date "02.2020" -Format "MM.yyyy"
$dateCutoff = $config.config.date
$result = foreach($i in $info){
    if(-Not($BLN -contains $i.SCAN_USER)){


        $entryDate = Get-Date $i.SCAN_DATE -Format "MM.yyyy"


        if($entryDate -eq $dateCutoff){
        $i
        }
     }
   $result | Out-File $config.config.path.output 
   Write-Host $i
   $config.config.path.output + "\" + $info | Out-File -Append $config.config.path.output 
}
```